# How to schedule a job in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, scheduler

In MySql DB, How to populate a specific table with the data of an excel file every day.

I want this job to run every morning at 8.00am.

How can i do this?

Comment: This question is too broad.  Can you narrow your question down?  Do you already know how to parse the excel file to get it in your database?  Have you written a program to do this or do you need help with that also?  If so, those should be two different questions.

Comment: You might not be able to do this with mysqls scheduler, but might be forced to run a cronjob or windows scheduler process. But until we know what kind of thing does the conversion from excel to whatever, we could not say.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with MySQL Workbench. You need some external timer service (cron job in linux/mac, scheduler service in Win) to run a batch file to make the import.